# wpf datepicker with highlighted dates

Tags: wpf, datepicker

In WPF DatePicker there's some method to highlight days that is in a List like BlackoutDates but selectable?

I want to present to user the days where I have some data in my db.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish it that takes little effort:

Inherit default styles for Calendar and CalendarDayButton and make some small changes:

```
<local:DateIsInListConverter x:Key="DateIsInListConverter" />

<Style x:Key="CustomCalendarDayButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CalendarDayButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CalendarDayButton}}">    
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DateIsInListConverter}">
                    <Binding />
                    <Binding ElementName="MyWindow" Path="HighlightedDates" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataTrigger.Binding>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="CustomCalendarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Calendar}}">
    <Setter Property="CalendarDayButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomCalendarDayButtonStyle}" />
</Style>
```

The second Binding in the MultiBinding is to your list of interesting dates and here is the implementation of DateIsInListConverter:

```
public class DateIsInListConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length < 2 || !(values[0] is DateTime) || !(values[1] is IEnumerable<DateTime>))
            return false;

        var date = (DateTime) values[0];
        var dateList = (IEnumerable<DateTime>) values[1];

        return dateList.Contains(date);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now use the CustomCalendarStyle on a DatePicker and you are done:

```
<DatePicker CalendarStyle="{StaticResource CustomCalendarStyle}" />
```

For a complete example with a reusable HighlightDatePicker, check out my GitHub repo: https://github.com/cmyksvoll/HighlightDatePicker

Comment: Great answer and example (with sample)!  Added one more feature, a highlight brush per date to group different types of dates with colors.  New brush property in the HighlightedDate class and HighlightedDateBrushConverter converter.

Comment: How do I get SelectedDateChanged event with HighlightDatePicker to run my method in main code (not in th HighlightDatePicker class). I'm getting the error:
`ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type`

Comment: @michal Do you mean like this(?):
MainWindow.xaml:
SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_OnSelectedDateChanged"

MainWindow.xaml.cs:
        private void DatePicker_OnSelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Selected date changed");
        }

Answer (score 0):

You will have to override the control template of the DayButton and add a datatrigger which looks for your property to show up highlighted.